# UILabel height with autolayout not working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I need a dynamic height label based on text length. I have set lines = 0, and Line break = word wrap.

[image: uilabel setting]

But its not working

[image: set text]

[image: result]

Is there any setting that I've missed? Seems like the default behavior is not wrapping, but i have changed it to "word wrap" but the label height is still not expanding.

Comment: Can you please show all the constraints given?

Comment: If you added the height constraints then please remove it

Comment: No i don't set height constraint. only top, leading, and trailing to safe area. and second label top constraint to first label, leading and trailing to safe area.

Comment: Very well asked, with amazingly complete info, especially since it’s so hard to show storyboard settings clearly. You really worked hard to prepare this question! Much appreciated. But given what you’ve shown, the height should definitely grow. Could you post the project on github or similar?  I’ll be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: And what are the constraints of second label?

Comment: set Line break = truncate tail, and decrease the first label's content vertical hugging priority less than label2 and check or do opposite also and check if it works.

Comment: [Is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554130/autolayout-to-dynamically-size-uilabel-height-and-width) related to what are you looking for?

Comment: Remove second label constraints and then run and test

Comment: Please don't post code as an image - it's not searchable

Comment: Thanks all, i've found the answer. The code in this answer has caused this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145859/1799096

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did everything you did:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.label1.text = "adsfadsf adf adfasdf adfadf adsfadf adfafasdfa adfadf adfadff adsfadfasdf adsfadfasf"
}
```

[image]

[image]

And this is what I got:

[image]

That's what you should get too. If you aren't, something else is going on.

Comment: Suggestion: use the View Debugger to see if the label boundaries are where they should be. Maybe the label is stretching out to the right somehow.

Comment: you are correct, something else is causing this.. I searched for UILabel extension in the project and found a code like like in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145859/1799096

Comment: i deleted the extension, and the UI label is back to normal, thanks

Comment: I continued this project from someone, so little bit confused why it's not working

Comment: Sometimes deleting everything _except_ the code that should be working shows you that that code does indeed work, and that the problem was in the other stuff. :)